# List Appending with outputs from machine learning function

Tags: r, machine-learning, dplyr, cluster-analysis, list-comparison

Please excuse the title for lack of a better phrase describing my question.

I'm running cluster stability analysis function out of 'flexclust' package, which runs bootstrap sampling on your dataset, calculate this thing called "Random Index" per each value of k (the range which I get to specify).

The function lets you try multiple distance metrics and clustering methods, and I want to run the function for every one of distance&method combination, find the best k based on each k's mean + median.

I've basically written nested for loops, initializing vector for each of the column: (name, distance metric, method, and best k). And calling a data.frame() to stitch all of them together.

```r
###############################################################################################
df = data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*100, 1, .5), ncol=4)) #random df for testing purpose

cl_stability <- function(df, df.name, k_low, k_high)
{
  cluster.distance = c("euclidean","manhattan")
  cluster.method = c("kmeans","hardcl","neuralgas")

  for (dist in cluster.distance)
    {
      for (method in cluster.method)
        {
          j = 1
          while (j <= length(cluster.distance)*length(cluster.method))
            {
              df.names = rep(c(df.name),length(cluster.distance)*length(cluster.method))
              distances = c()
              methods = c()
              best.k.s = c()

              ip = as.data.frame((bootFlexclust(df, k = k_low:k_high, multicore = TRUE,
                                                FUN = "cclust", dist = d, method = m))@rand)

              best_k = names(which.max(apply(ip, 2, mean) + apply(ip, 2, median))) #this part runs fine when I run them outside of the function

              distances[j] = d
              methods[j] = m
              best.k.s[j] = best_k
              j = j + 1
              final = data.frame(df.names,distances,methods,best.k.s)
            }
          }
    }
  return(final)
}
```

**Expected result would be a dataframe with 7 columns (name, distance metric, method, and best k, 2nd best, 3rd best, and the worst based on median+mean criteria.).**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqpp0.jpg

Comment: Mr. Rand is not random... And stability of results does not imply quality - they can be stable but bad!

Comment: good point, you're right the best k from stability wouldn't always agree with the best results from different evaluation frameworks, which I have already done, and I wanted to compare the output from the stability analysis and choose the 'final' k